# Can't ping any device on the LAN--incorrect interface setup?

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ethernet

Thanks in advance for reading this question! I just installed Ubuntu Server (CLI only) 16.04.3 LTS on my Dell Inspiron with a Centrino 2. I have a wired connection to my router, but I can't ping it or any other device on the network, nor can I ping any Google server. Attempting to ping anything other than the loopback interface yields "Destination Host Unreachable." I think it's a problem with the way I've configured my interfaces, but I can't be sure. I have added the output of ip and my routing table below:

```
ip addr show enp9s0

2: enp9s0: <N0-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC address> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.0.30/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp9s0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway        Genmask        Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0        192.168.0.1    0.0.0.0        UG    0      0        0 enp9s0
192.168.0.0    0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0  U     0      0        0 enp9s0
```

AFAIK, these are correct, right? But my experience with networking is pretty limited, so they could also be wrong in some way that I didn't anticipate. The interface enp9s0 is my wired Ethernet controller, and I have it configured to have a static IP. I have confirmed that there are no IP conflicts with other devices on the LAN. Just in case it might help, here is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp9s0
iface enp9s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.30
gateway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255

dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide!

edit 1:

This morning I checked the BIOS settings regarding both network interfaces. Just to be sure, I toggled them with a boot in between, and they had no effect. On a whim, I decided to boot into a live Ubuntu desktop, only to find that the wireless interface works exactly as it should, but the Ethernet interface still does not. I think that the problems with the wireless interface stem from not having the wpasupplicant package installed. Unfortunately, this package isn't preexisting on the Server distribution, and I can't install it without attempting some serious apt hackery. The Ethernet interface not working is a bit concerning, though...perhaps a driver issue? or an unseen hardware issue? No matter what I try, I can't seem to get the `state UP`.

Comment: Can you ping your **enp9s0** interface `ping -c 3 192.168.0.30`?

Comment: Hey, thank you for responding! I can, yes. I hadn't thought of trying that. Pinging the enp9s0 interface seems to work.

Comment: So, the interface is up. Can you trace the route to the gateway for example `traceroute 192.168.0.1`? It looks silly but may give us additional information about your problem.

Comment: It looks like I only have `tracepath`. I hope that this will also be useful? `tracepath -b 192.168.0.1` gives:
`1?: [LOCALHOST]                                                          pmtu 1500
1:   192.168.0.30 (192.168.0.30)                                    1434.933ms !H
      Resume: pmtu 1500`

Comment: Couldn't help but notice your interface is listed as `DOWN`. Have you checked your cable/router/interfaces?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, but I'm not sure exactly what that refers to? The interface is up, by <NO-CARRIER,...,UP>. Running `ifdown enp9s0` or similar simply removes the UP field from the bracketed text. What does the `state DOWN` mean?

Comment: I have tried a different cable, and I've also tried bringing it to my work network, but it doesn't seem to work there, either. If I go to the router homepage at `192.168.0.1`, I don't see my computer listed under connected devices.

Comment: Try to check BIOS settings regarding network interface.